# Finding correlation between nonlinear variables sets & forecasting

Tags: correlation, forecasting, nonlinear-regression

I have two data sets. Data Set A is % over/under **budget** for a list of non-related projects. Data Set B is % over/under **time** for the same list of projects. Here is a sample of the data

[image]

Will I be able to use the Person-regression to find out correlation here? - Correl(array1, array 2) - Or since I have negative numbers will I not be able to use this?
After I find correlation, I then just use P value to make sure it is significant, correct?

I want to be able to forecast and say if a project is going to be X% over time it will also likely be Y% over budget.

[image]

Comment: Small terminology issue: These are not two datasets, but two variables in the same dataset. Small practical issue: Please provide the data so that they be copied and pasted. Provision in an image is much less helpful: who wants to type in 32 numbers with lots of decimal places?

Comment: Negative values are in themselves absolutely no barrier to calculating a correlation or a regression.

Answer (score 1):

You want linear regression rather than correlation. A linear regression model will predict the percentage over time for any new project given its percentage over budget, or vice versa. There is no need for significance tests or *p*-values. You can use [prediction intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_interval) to give your predictions while also showing how much uncertainty there is (presumably a lot).

Comment: Ok, I think I get what your saying. But, I'm still having a hard time understanding how a linear regression will give me what I want when I have some negative and positive correlations in my data. I added the chart for a visual. Aren't linear regressions only useful if you either have a positive or negative correlation - not both. As the chart shows, when projects go over time, budget is also likely to go over, and similarly when projects are under time. What I need is to be able to say as project x goes 10% over or under time it will likely go Y amount over. Maybe I'm just confused =/

Comment: Yeah, you seem pretty confused. There is only one obvious correlation to compute for your data, which is the correlation between percentage over time and percentage over budget. Also, the right plot to draw here is not two lines like you've drawn, but a scatterplot where one of of the percentages is on the *x*-axis and the other is on the *y*-axis.

Answer (score 1):

Some comments:

Correlation looks at the relationship between deviations from the mean of two variables, so negative values are not a barrier to calculating the correlation.

Correlation can be a good simple measure of your data, but you state you want to be able to predict how over-budget a project is based on how over-time the project is, so you want to be doing regression.  Your confusion of this with correlation may come from the fact that linear regression of two variables uses the correlation coefficient between those variables to get the relationship.  But you can't use the correlation alone to make predictions.

If you suspect your variables are related in a non-linear way, this will still be done using the regular linear regression function that your statistics software uses.  Just include a extra columns of data that is made up of those nonlinear terms (e.g. calculate both a $(\% \mathrm{overtime})$ and $(\% \mathrm{overtime})^2$ column, and feed them into your software's linear regression function to fit a quadratic function.)

If you have particular questions about how to do that with your software, you might want to edit your answer so it focuses on the problem you want to solve.  If it's clear what you are looking for, you will probably find some additional help :)

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the statement "Correlation also doesn't have any p-value" - it is possible to perform a significance test for correlation.

Comment: @Silverfish You are 100% correct, I am deeply ashamed :P

Comment: @Blue_vision Thanks for the clarification, I was able to find the linear regression line and the standard error of estimates (SEE) so I am now where I need to be. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @A.Klise If you feel Blue_vision has answered your question to your satisfaction, please accept it by clicking on the check mark under the voting arrows.